# Need line drawing algorithm for simulating natural pencil

Tags: algorithm, graphics, line

I'm writing a drawing program that uses a pressure sensitive table for input.  I'd like to be able to simulate the soft pencil effect that many other art programs have (such as Paint Tool SAI, Art Rage).  Technique I'm using at the moment is functional, but is missing the cleanness I see in more professional programs.

My algorithm at the moment works like this:

- Create a bitmap representing the head of the brush.  This is just a transparent bitmap with a black circle drawn on it.  The circle has an inner radius that is solid black and an outer radius.  The blackness linearly fades from opaque to transparent as you move from the inner to the outer radius.

  Capture input events from my tablet.  Each point contains an (x, y) coordinate as well as a pressure value

  For every point after the first one, draw a line from the previous point to the current one.  This is done by drawing (daubing) the brush bitmap several times between the two points.  The step size between each daub is chosen so there is an overlap between subsequent daubs.

This works reasonably well, but the result is a line that is somewhat blobby and jagged.

- One thing I need to do is somehow smooth out the input points so that the stroke as a whole is smooth.

  The other thing I need to do is figure out how to 'drag' the brush head along this path to make the stroke.  If the spacing is too far apart, the stroke looks like a line of circles.  If too close together, the stroke builds up on itself and becomes very dark.  (I tried to fix this by attenuating the brush by the spacing.  This does make things more consistent, but stops the stroke from being fully opaque).

Anyhow, I'd expect that there's a lot of research already done on this, if only I knew where to look.  Please let me know if there are any better pencil drawing algorithms out there.

Comment: Hmm.  Looks like the blobbiness was coming from round off error.  I was unintentionally aligning my brush sprites to whole pixels.  I started using fractional coordintaes and things are looking much better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing the new circle over what has already been drawn, using the standard blending functions (so that regions of overlap get a higher opacity), you need to keep the **maximum** opacity so far.

Only after you have built up the complete stroke (as on a white sheet), you can blend it to the existing line art.

The picture illustrates the difference between blending and keeping the maximum opacity.
[image]

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but giving the brush the ability to 'build up' is one of the things I'm aiming for.  The brush you describe above is the sort of thing that Photoshop does - however, this leads to a lack of darkening whenever the stroke self intersects.

Comment: You cant' at the same time prevent the brush to increase opacity when it overwrites itself and increase it when it self intersects: a local algorithm cannot make the difference.